# How to resolve parent/child URL in Angular JS (ngRoute)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-directive

Unable to open this path /site/recentposts when typed in browser URL , /site works okay but need to
use this path /site/recentposts when typed in browser URL to open page /site/recentposts.

site : controller ,
action method : recentposts

http://someurl.com/site/recentposts executes & show some page(view). Now i need to show this same page when typed through browser URL.

also .when('/site/recentposts') does not execute in angular.

```
    // configure our routes
    site.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
       $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/site/recentposts', {
            templateUrl: 'site/recentposts',
            controller: 'RecentPostsController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/search', {
            templateUrl: 'site/search'
            //controller: 'RecentPostsController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/writepost', {
            templateUrl: 'site/writepost'

        });

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: Please provide more info about the server. The request/response headers to/from server would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a error 404?
This could be a webserver related Problem. Maybe you have the route /site configured to point to your angular file, but the webserver doesn't know how to respond on /site/recentposts

If this doesn't help: What do you get when typing in the /site/recentposts URL in your browser?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what this means:"http://someurl.com/site/recentposts executes & show some page(view). Now i need to show this same page when typed through browser URL. " What does your browser show when you type in the URL?